# Android Application crashes in Alpha testing, but works fine locally

Tags: android

I have an Android application that I've put onto alpha testing. I've uploaded 5 different APK's with the first four working perfectly.

I've now uploaded the fifth and downloaded it to a phone, and it crashes straight away, I can't even see the first activity.

Is this just because it's not finished uploading to the servers or is it an issue with the app?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of Error or Exceptions do you get? What do you mean by testing locally? What android versions do you run it on?

Comment: It just says `Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped.

Comment: Please post error Log..

Comment: Where will I get the error log?

Comment: Use [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html#startingLogcat)

Comment: I've done this any there is no errors or problems with the application, it's only when I downlaod it through the test link provided by google play that it isn't working, all of my other APK's worked perfectly, my question was, do you think it's because the APK hasn't been completely uploaded to the google play store?

Comment: Did you run proguard when generating APK?

Comment: no I didn't, How would that help if the other APK file's uploaded perfectly?

Comment: It always depends on the APK content. Proguard often tends to generate such problems. As you said you have uploaded 5 DIFFERENT APK's.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some Ad maybe you give a certificate, that is different. 
To see if that's the problem, try to upload you apk (the one that you create for market) on your device, and see if it still crash (certificate problems).

Comment: What do you mean by `If you use some Ad`?

Comment: For example AdMob, or something that require your certificate key

Comment: No, I don't use anything like that

Comment: Anyway, try to run the apk that you create for the market and see if it works fine

Comment: You can just send the apk via email to yourself end the install it, easy way for me

Comment: So I've just done it and it work work, how do I figure out what the problem is if it works perfectly when I upload it through Eclipse

Comment: Did you install the apk that you generate by export your application from eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I did adb install (file location)

Comment: I'm going to create a new APK file and manually upload it to the phone before adding it to the google play store alpha testing see if there was just a glitch in the APK file, I did remove some permissions from the manifest file that I didn't think I needed, could this have been the problem do you think

Comment: Yeah updated the application version as it wouldn't uplaod to Google play store otherwise

Comment: Sure can be, maybe you think that some permission is useless, but you need them ;)

Comment: Ok then, I'll create a new APK file and upload it through the command prompt, and if that doesn't work, add the permissions I took out last time and see if it works then, I'll let you know how it goes and thanks for the help

Comment: I've just created a new APK file for it and it's uploaded and working perfectly! Really strange, Don't have a clue why, do you have an idea?

Comment: Maybe, you upload some bugs that then you fixed